# How could i manage to open a popup window in a secondary monitor if it exists using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How could I manage to open a popup window in a secondary monitor if it exists using javascript??
Thank you so much...

Comment: Use the 4th parameter for `window.open`, which is an optional param that allows you to specify which monitor to position the popup in (by default, primary monitor)

Comment: @Ian: `window.open` doesn't have a parameter like that, unless you can prove me wrong?

Comment: @Cerbrus Haha I can't, I just wanted to see if people were paying attention

Comment: @Ian, then please don't provide false information.

Comment: @Cerbrus Nah, I will. It was just a comment

Comment: Well, I will just ignore it. Window.open, great!.....

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect "secondary monitors" with JavaScript. JS doesn't have access to hardware, like that.

Not to mention the fact that users generally dislike browsers taking control of windows (Resizing / moving them, etc)

Comment: I was thinking of activex control usage to manage SystemInformation Class(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.MonitorCount) or try to use it first with some other scripting language like VB, and try to share it with javascript somehow.

Comment: @Manuel: You are aware that ActiveX controls aren't well supported?

Comment: I´m awared of that particular issue, but is just for a local application using only internet explorer8, on windows7

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest asking a question about ActiveX controls and the interaction with them.
If you want to, could you mark this as the answer to this specific question?

Comment: Could be better, yes. I´ll, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, and thank for that, if a user has two monitors is his decision to choose what applications are shown in which monitor, not the other way around.